# How to use environment variables in Sveltekit 1.0?

Tags: environment-variables, vite, sveltekit

I have an .env file which contains two sensitive items and two non-sensitive. Running Sveltekit 1.0 and using Netlify Serverless functions with a db-helper file which has

```
require('dotenv').config();
const dbName = process.env.MONGODB_DATABASE;
```

and similarly gets the other variables. However, this crashes with error "cant find module 'dotenv'!

I tried, with same error ..

```
const dbName = import.meta.env.MONGODB_DATABASE
```

I tried process.env['MONGODB_DATABASE'] and import.meta.env['MONGODB_DATABASE']. Failed.

I tried prefixing env vars with VITE using both process.env and import.meta.env with and without [' '] wrapper. Failed.

I read that you dont have to explicitly load dotenv as Vite does this. Tried without. Failed.

Has anyone got a solution to this?

Comment: Is this crash in the client-side code? I.e. in the web browser not in node.js.

Comment: Runs fine locally. Deployed to Netlify it crashes. So server side. The web app runs fine otherwise on Netlify and the build shows no errors. Its how to handle the environment variables, server-side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environment variables should be accessed through these modules:

- [`$env/dynamic/private`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-private)
- [`$env/dynamic/public`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-dynamic-public)
- [`$env/static/private`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-private)
- [`$env/static/public`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$env-static-public)

Public restricts them to those prefixed with `PUBLIC_` (which can be configured).

There is some additional documentation for some adapters regarding the loading of these variables, e.g. for [the Node adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables), but there is nothing specific for [Netlify](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-netlify).

Looking at [the Netlify docs](https://docs.netlify.com/environment-variables/get-started/#create-environment-variables), it looks like you have to use its UI/tools or [a Netlify config](https://docs.netlify.com/environment-variables/get-started/#create-variables-with-a-netlify-configuration-file) to load variables rather than using an `.env` file:

> With the Netlify CLI, use env:set to update a site environment variable, env:import to import from an updated .env file, and env:unset to delete a site environment variable and all of its contextual values.

Comment: Thanks. I cant figure out yet how to implement the linked docs methods but thanks for these. Meanwhile, I set up the environment variables on Netlify and removed the require('dotenv').config() from my db_helper file and the deployed app is now working fine, so that a workaround till I get my head around the documented methods. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I was using

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

which worked locally but gave a "cannot find module dotenv" when deployed (to Netlify). I found that in I used "import" instead of "require" then it worked ..

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```

So thats a solution. But, H.B. correctly pointed out the new sveltekit way env variables should be used. Thanks for that.

PS. The require/import also fails/works for jsonwebtoken so use *import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'* instead of *const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')*